# Setting a minim value for the y axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a d3 plot based on [Focus+Context](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) example.

It works fine, but I'm not able to set a minimal value for the y-axis.

I taught I understood the theory of input domain and output range (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch07.html), but it seems I'm missing something.

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/cecdsmnv/1/

I want the y axis to go from `minAltitude` to `maxAltitude`

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the right ideas.

The settings you made for `y.domain` will be overwritten in line 72. Change around line to (switch min and max):

```
  var z = 50;
  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y.domain([minAltitude, maxAltitude + z]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());
```

I added a z padding variable there in case you want some heading space at the top.

Comment: oh... I'm so blind... thanks to you I say that actually my setting of the `y.domain` with `minAltitude` and `maxAltitude` was being overwritten down below... Thanks for pointing this out.